# Can I run Android, Mac or Windows apps on Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, mac, webapps

My situation is quite special, I like to buy an Ubuntu Phone for more safety and for having an open source OS. But I'm deaf and I need a special app for being able to telephone with a **sign-language translator**.

However those apps are only built for Android, Mac or Windows. I've found Android and Mac emulators for Linux, but is there another way, or if not, anyway using emulators.

Comment: I think right now you are out of luck, I can be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this won't work without emulators like [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) (you'll probably want the [ARM version](http://wiki.winehq.org/ARM)).

But that's exactly what emulators are here for. They aren't actually that much of a hassle to use, and don't eat up too many resources.

I'm afraid I don't know of any serious sign-language translators having a native Linux build or being open source. So emulators will have to do for now.

Comment: Wine is not an emulator.  It is right on their website.  - "Wine Is Not an Emulator" https://www.winehq.org/about/

Comment: @goddard: Sure, you're right. But for all intents and purposes, it fills the role of one and I didn't want to be more complicated than necessary.

Comment: ok sure, but better not to say untrue things.  The term emulator probably isn't any more complicated then compatibility layer.  Also you should make a suggest for the user like PlayOnLinux, or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Android apps working in Linux with Chrome and ARchon.

The process is slightly involved, but not too bad.

Check out - https://github.com/vladikoff/chromeos-apk/blob/master/archon.md

Also you should let the developers of those apps know you would like Linux support and maybe you can post what that app is.  Do they have an open API?  If so we might be able to make our own GUI for their service.

**UPDATE :** new project - http://www.shashlik.io/ showing a lot of promise and looks pretty good.

Comment: It is this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.nwise.mymmxtc.tess (I'm afraid that the text is german). The developer of this app declined to support Linux...